# How to do mysql search which excludes duplicate records

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to perform a search on a table with structure like
id, mls_id, address, agent_id.  What I would like to do is pull all the records for agent_id but not pull more than one if there is same mls.  For example:

```
Select * From table WHERE agent_ID = 1234
```

might pull up 5 records but let's say two of the records have an mls_id that is the same.  Is there a way to just pull one of those and still keep all the other results in tact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This seems to do the trick:**

What it does is to choose the record with the minimal id from those that have the same mls_id

```
SELECT id, mls_id, address, agent_id
FROM MyTable t1
WHERE t1.agent_id=1 AND t1.id = 
    (SELECT Min(t2.id) 
     FROM MyTable t2 
     WHERE agent_id=1 AND t2.mls_id=t1.mls_id 
     GROUP BY t2.mls_id)
```

Here is the fiddle example : [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2cc8/8)

Comment: Wow - that works.  Far more complicated mysql statement than I have ever created before.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM table
WHERE agent_ID = 1234
```

Using the `DISTINCT` keyword will drop duplicate records from your result set.

Comment: That gave me the same results.  I am still getting three records that have identical mls_id fields.  If I just do

SELECT DISTINCT mls_id FROM table WHERE agent_ID = 1234 that will give me distinct results but I then don't get the additional fields needed - like address, city, st etc.

Comment: `Select Distinct * From table` is simply the same as `SELECT * From table`, since all rows are unique in a standard table.